# Send Email in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, email, razor, smtp, umbraco

I am setting up a function to send out mails(as confirmation for orders but thats a later matter).

Problem is that the mails are to be sent from the companys exchange server and so far all i have gotten is connection failed.

I am in communication with the server tech trying to find out whats wrong, and since its been a while since i set up email(on the cms side) i might be making a stupid mistake, so maybe somebody here will catch it :)

web.config: (port number specified by server tech)

(all info replaced with generic but consistent names for safety ofc)

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="info@mydomain.com">
        <network host="smtp.ourexchangeserver.dk" userName="info@mydomain.com" password="secret" port="26" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

razor script test:

```
      @{
    try {
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("myadress@gmail.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("info@mydomain.com");

message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
            {
               <p> error: <br/> @ex.ToString() </p> 
            }
}
```

Error caught in exception:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
 System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that they are giving you the port credentials are of exchange server's and not of *Exchange Web services Managed API*.

Second is that you would require to specify Fields when sending emails using SMTP server based on the configurations. e.g

```
   OMsg1.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"] = "smtp"; // ypur SMTP serner name

        OMsg1.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"] = 25;
```

and like wise.

Please find below link to send email using SMTP in C# and you could make a RAZOR replica of it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1602115.aspx

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Find the below link which will help you to send mail from UMBRACO. Send email in razor macro

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/22536-Send-email-in-razor-macro